# What is the rule for duplicating the last letter when adding "-ed"?

Tags: orthography, past-participles, doubled-consonants

I wonder if there is any rule for doubling the *p* at the end of a stem. For example:

> *stop — stopped*

but

> *help — helped*

Comment: The easiest rule to remember is: when a word ends with a consonant, preceded by a single vowel, then that consonant is doubled in the past simple tense. But in American English if a word ends with a single "l" it is left alone. BrEng *travelled* AmEng *traveled*

Comment: @Mari-LouA thank you for short description, it makes sense

Comment: Perhaps you would like to visit ELL [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) our sister site?

Comment: @Mari-Lou: when you ***answered,*** you should have said there were numerous exceptions. For another example, ***compelled***. There is a more complete rule which says that for multi-syllable words in American English, you double the final letter only if the last syllable ends with a consonant, contains a single-letter short vowel, and is accented. But again, it has exceptions.

Comment: So for OP's 'What is the rule' read 'Is there anything we could even term a rule of thumb . . .'.

Comment: @PeterShor I gave an *easy* rule **and** I gave him the link to a more complete answer. Anyway, I thought comments were not considered answers.